# Change full column of dates in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, formatting, columnsorting

I have a full column of dates that are formatted like dd/mm/yyyy

I want the change the full column so that they are formatted like yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 2):

Use `dmy` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
dmy("15/10/21")
[1] "2021-10-15"
```

Comment: how would I do this for a full column. for example the column is called "Date"?

Comment: Considering the dataframe called df: df$Date <- dmy(df$Date)